# Transform delimited fields to lines with name and value

Tags: shell, awk

File a is containing field names:

```
timestamp,name,ip
```

File b contains values:

```
2021-12-17 16:01:19.970,app1,10.0.0.0
2021-12-17 16:01:19.260,app1,10.0.0.1
```

When I use awk as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\n"} {if(NR%3==0){print "----"};$1=$1;print;}' b
```

I get:

```
----
2021-12-17 16:01:19.970
app1
10.0.0.0
----
2021-12-17 16:01:19.260
app1
10.0.0.1
```

Any way to merge key:value in each line?
The output I want is:

```
----
timestamp:2021-12-17 16:01:19.970
app:app1
ip:10.0.0.0
----
timestamp:2021-12-17 16:01:19.260
app:app1
ip:10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="," }
FNR==NR{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    heading[i]=$i
  }
  next
}
{
  print "----"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    print heading[i]":"$i
  }
}
' filea fileb
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS="," }           ##Stating BEGIN section of this program and set FS to , here.
FNR==NR{                  ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when filea is being read.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){     ##Traversing through all fields here.
    heading[i]=$i         ##Setting heading array index as i and value as current field.
  }
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print "----"            ##printing ---- here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){     ##Traversing through all fields here.
    print heading[i]":"$i ##Printing heading with index i and colon and value of current field.
  }
}
' filea fileb             ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: So, If I have 32 fields, I should repeat ORS heading[1]":"$1?

Comment: @RickyWu, Sure, I have changed code accordingly, we need not to hardcode anything now, you could try it now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Yes, it works well, thanks! Can we move read header into BEGIN? then I can use this script works with pipeline much more easy?

Comment: @RickyWu, you mean file's header? If yes then no; files will never be read in BEGIN section. In which file do you have headers?

Comment: There is no header in any files, I must prepare it manually